# Running sakis3g on a Dart card causes it to reboot

Tags: networking, arm, embedded-linux, 3g

I'm trying to use a 3G modem (USB dongle) on a Dart card (which is like a Raspberry Pi with a iMX6 CPU).

After reading a bit on the internet, I settled on running the following command (after doing the necessary mode switching for the dongle):

```
sakis3g connect OTHER=CUSTOM_TTY CUSTOM_TTY=ttyUSB4 APN=<my_apn> APN_USER=" " APN_PASS=" "
```

This command worked perfectly when I ran it in an Ubuntu machine with the same dongle. However, when I try to run it on my Dart it almost immediately resets the card:

```
root@var-som-mx6:~# ./sakis3g connect OTHER=CUSTOM_TTY CUSTOM_TTY=ttyUSB4 APN=<my_apn> APN_USER=" " APN_PASS=" "

usb 1-1: USB disconnect, d
U-Boot SPL 2013.10 (Nov 05 2015 - 15:35:08)
i.MX6Q SOC P-POP DDR EEPROM configuration
Part number: 
Assembly: 
Date of production: 2015 Oct 20
Ram size 1024
Boot Device : MMC1
Load image from RAW...


U-Boot 2013.10 (Nov 05 2015 - 15:35:08)

CPU:   Freescale i.MX6Q rev1.5 at 792 MHz
<and so on...>
```

What is happening here? Why is `sakis3g` resetting my card?

Comment: This isn't related to programming at all. Try for example SuperUser.

Comment: Sounds very much like a hardware issue, like turning the radio on causes the dongle to draw more current than the board can reliably supply. Can't really solve that with programming...

Comment: @JaggenSWE @Notlikethat I'm not sure what the problem is, so I can't really tell if the answer will be in code or not. But the `sakis3g` file is a bash script and the answer might require me to modify it, so isn't that a good place to ask this?

Comment: I'd start by modifying the script to make it plug in the dongle through a self-powered hub, and seeing whether that changes anything ;)